# iTextSharp sending PdfFormFieldvalues to a server

Tags: c#, pdf, submit, itext

For some reason I am not able to send PdfFormField values to my server. When I click submit button it only sends data from fields created with Acrobat to server but not fields created programmatically with iTextSharp. I am using c#.

This is how I create text field:

```
Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(x, y-h, x+w, y);
cb.SaveState();
PdfGState state = new PdfGState();

cb.SetGState(state);
state.FillOpacity = opac;
state.StrokeOpacity = bopac;
cb.Rectangle(x, y - h, w, h);
cb.FillStroke();
cb.RestoreState();
```

This is my submit button:

```
PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                Rectangle _rect;
                PdfFormField _Field1;

                _rect = new Rectangle(25, 15, 120, 40);
                PushbuttonField button = new PushbuttonField(writer, _rect, "Button0");
                button.BackgroundColor = new GrayColor(0.75f);
                button.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
                button.BorderWidth = 1;
                button.BorderStyle = PdfBorderDictionary.STYLE_BEVELED;
                button.TextColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
                button.FontSize = 12;
                button.Text = "Confirm Order";
                button.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_LEFT_LABEL_RIGHT;
                button.ScaleIcon = PushbuttonField.SCALE_ICON_ALWAYS;
                button.ProportionalIcon = true;
                button.IconHorizontalAdjustment = 0;
                _Field1 = button.Field;
                int flags = PdfAction.SUBMIT_XFDF | PdfAction.SUBMIT_INCLUDE_NO_VALUE_FIELDS;
                _Field1.Action = PdfAction.CreateSubmitForm(@"http://127.0.0.1/index.php", null, flags);
                writer.AddAnnotation(_Field1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't creating a form field in your code above, you're just creating a rectangle. Check out `TextField`

```
writer.AddAnnotation(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(writer, rect, "FirstName").GetTextField());
```